# Solve: $x∂z/∂x(z-2y^2)=(z-y∂z/∂y)(z-y^2-2x^3)$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The question is: $x∂z/∂x(z-2y^2)=(z-y∂z/∂y)(z-y^2-2x^3)$.

I am stuck with this question. Don't know how to approach. Please help.

Comment: Solve for x or y or z or (x,y,z)?

Comment: I don't know how this looks like a partial differential equation. Should this have tag number-theory instead?

Comment: @Aniket, we have to solve for z.

Comment: Edit the question with proper PD notations. Its a bit difficult to understand the actual equation.

Comment: Edited the question. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dz}{dt}=z$ , letting $z(0)=1$ , we have $z=e^t$

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=y$ , letting $y(0)=y_0$ , we have $y=y_0e^t=y_0z$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{x(z-2y^2)}{z-y^2-2x^3}=\dfrac{x(e^t-2y_0^2e^{2t})}{e^t-y_0^2e^{2t}-2x^3}$

Comment: Thanks doraemonpaul, this method is really useful.